# How to find lines of invariant points?

Tags: matrices, geometry, linear-transformations

Every time I try a question on this topic I get it wrong.

My textbook says:

> Invariant points satisfy $B\begin{pmatrix}u\\ v\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}u\\ v\end{pmatrix}$
>
> Re-write this as a system of equations.
>
> Check whether both equations are in fact the same.
>
> If so, they give a line of invariant points.

So I tried this question using that method (and the method needed for finding invariant lines):

> For [this] matrix, find any lines of invariant points and any other invariant lines through the origin.
>
> $\begin{pmatrix}3&-2\\ 4&-3\end{pmatrix}$

What I did was:
$\begin{pmatrix}3&-2\\ 4&-3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u\\ mu\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}u\\ v\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3u-2mu\\ 4u-3mu\end{pmatrix}$

These equations are not the same, so no lines of invariant points.

Then, to find invariant lines:

$\begin{pmatrix}3&-2\\ 4&-3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u\\ mu\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}u'\\ v'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3u-2mu\\ 4u-3mu\end{pmatrix}$

$4u-3mu=m\left(3u-2mu\right)$

$2m^2-6m+4\:=0\:\Rightarrow \:m\:=1\: $or$ \:m=2$

So the invariant lines should be $y=2x$ or $y=x$. As far as I know this is *sort of* right, except $y=x$ is apparently also a line of invariant points. What did I do wrong?

Comment: If $m=1$ then $3u-2mu=4u-3mu$.

Comment: Oh. So I can't rule out the equations despite the fact that they don't appear the same?

Comment: right. Instead, you should set them equal to eachother and see what solutions you get. In this case, you have: $u(3-2m)=u(4-3m)$ which evidently has solutions if a) $u=0$ or b) $3-2m=4-3m$. You can discard the first, and from the second you can solve to get $m=1$.

Comment: That was an accident, sorry. Will fix.

Comment: “The equations are the same” doesn’t mean that they’re _identical_, but that they’re _equivalent_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$\mathbf{B} = \left [ \begin{matrix} b_{11} & b_{12} \\ b_{21} & b_{22} \end{matrix} \right ], \quad \mathbf{p} = \left [ \begin{matrix} u \\ v \end{matrix} \right ]$$
If $\mathbf{p}$ is an invariant point with respect to $\mathbf{B}$, then
$$\mathbf{B} \mathbf{p} = \mathbf{p} \tag{1}\label{NA1}$$
which is equivalent to
$$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
b_{11} u + b_{12} v &= u \\
b_{21} u + b_{22} v &= v \end{aligned} \right .$$
and
$$\left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
(b_{11} - 1) u + b_{12} v &= 0 \\
b_{21} u + (b_{22} - 1) v &= 0 \end{aligned} \right . \tag{2}\label{NA2}$$
To find invariant points, you solve $\eqref{NA2}$ for $u$ and $v$.  In some cases, the solution is not a single point, but a line. If the matrix is all zeros, then all points are invariant.

---

Let's examine $\mathbf{B} = \left [ \begin{matrix} 1 & 4 \\ 2 & -1 \end{matrix} \right ]$. Substituting to $\eqref{NA2}$ we get
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
(1 - 1)u + 4 v &= 0 \\
2 u + (-1 - 1) v &= 0 \\
\end{aligned} \right . \quad \iff \quad \left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
4 v &= 0 \\
2 u - 2 v &= 0 \\
\end{aligned}\right .$$
The only solution to this is $u = v = 0$. So, this matrix has an invariant point at origin.

---

Let's examine $\mathbf{B} = \left [ \begin{matrix} 3 & -2 \\ 4 & -3 \end{matrix} \right ]$. Substituting to $\eqref{NA2}$ we get
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
2 u - 2 v &= 0 \\
4 u - 4 v &= 0 \\
\end{aligned}\right .$$
If we divide the upper one by 2, or the lower one by 4, we get the same equation: $u - v = 0$. Thus, this matrix has an invariant line $u = v$.